# .Net, How do I iterate through JSon object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to iterate through each key/value of the following:

```
"sprites": {
    "back_female": null,
    "back_shiny_female": null,
    "back_default": "some url"
    "front_female": null,
    "front_shiny_female": null,
    "front_shiny": "some url"
},
```

In my ApiCaller.cs:

```
    JObject PokeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(StringResponse);
    JObject SpriteList = PokeObject["sprites"].Value<JObject>();
    List<string> Sprites = new List<string>();

     foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in SpriteList) {
                    if(entry.Value != null){
                        Sprites.Add(entry.Value);
                    }
                }
```

I am getting:

```
 Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>
```

Could anybody help me solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Show you real json

Comment: in your foreach KeyValuePair<string, string> should be KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> based on the error

Comment: try deserializing as a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ToObject<T>` method:

```
var Sprites = PokeObject["sprites"]
    .ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .ToList();
```